# Print new line after each last occurrence of array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php array which I need to print a new line break after each occurrence, here's how it looks:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [productid] => 2
        [productname] = "Product A"
        [categoryid] => 1
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [productid] => 4
        [productname] = "Product B"
        [categoryid] => 2
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [productid] => 4
        [productname] = "Product C"
        [categoryid] => 2
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [productid] => 4
        [productname] = "Product D"
        [categoryid] => 3
    )
    [4] => Array (
        [productid] => 4
        [productname] = "Product E"
        [categoryid] => 3
    )
)
```

So I loop through my products like so:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $index => $product) {
   echo "<div class='column'>";
   echo "$product->productname";
   echo "</div>";
   /* TODO: Echo br element for each new categoryid */
}?>
```

This works well, and gives me the HTML output as:

```
<div class="column">
    Product A
</div>
<div class="column">
    Product B
</div>
<div class="column">
    Product C
</div>
<div class="column">
    Product D
</div>
<div class="column">
    Product E
</div>
```

However, I need to force a new row with `<br>` for each new category, so my HTML output would become:

```
<div class="column">
    Product A
</div>
<br> <!-- Breakline because this is the last item in this categoryid -->
<div class="column">
    Product B
</div>
<div class="column">
    Product C
</div>
<br> <!-- Breakline because this is the last item in this categoryid -->
<div class="column">
    Product D
</div>
<div class="column">
    Product E
</div>
<br> <!-- Breakline because this is the last item in this categoryid -->
```

I figured I could keep track of the last used categoryid, and echo if it's not the same like this at the start of my foreach:

```
if ($lastProductCategory == $products->categoryid) { echo '<br'>};
```

and at the end of the foreach:

```
$lastProductCategory = $products->categoryid;
```

But this doesn't work for the first item, because $lastProductCategory isn't set yet, but if I move where $lastProductCategory is defined, it now inserts `<br>` after every product.

What is the best way to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not set the categoryId initially?

Answer (score 2):

should do the trick:

```
<?php
$lastId = null;
foreach ($products as $index => $product) {
    if ($lastId !== null && $lastId !== $product->categoryid) { // Probably should be $product['categoryid'], but assuming $product->productname is correct then this should be too
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    $lastId = $product->categoryid; // Probably should be $product['categoryid'], but assuming $product->productname is correct then this should be too

    echo "<div class='column'>";
    echo $product->productname; // Not sure why its not $product['productname'], but you said it works :x
    echo "</div>";
}
echo "<br/>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To continue in what you already started, you can add a condition "if the last is_null" add a breakline for the first occurrence

But for good practice, i suggest you to get rearrange your array with categoryId as index and element as subindex. And loop over categories instead of items

I share you my phpsandbox i made for you

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5ab6c3c81a2d7155d6df5e9d071f1392d649f339

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, If the categoryid is appeared last in the index then you have to echo **br** tag

You need to try the below condition, with the `array_slice()` that returns an array from a particular index to the end of the array and `array_column()` that will return an array for the particular column

```
foreach ($products as $index => $product) {
   echo "<div class='column'>";
   echo $product["productname"];
   echo "</div>";
   // Just check from categorid id exist or not just ahead of this current index if not then echo <br>
   if( !in_array($product["categoryid"], array_column( array_slice($products,$index+1), "categoryid") ) ){
    echo "<br>";
   }
}
```

Check the output here https://paiza.io/projects/rEpmdSU7p3LVqCK5S8UirA?language=php